# 'Resuming' Ubuntu after battery died

Tags: ubuntu, boot, osx, dual-boot

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 alongside OSX, usually booting into Ubuntu using rEFInd.

Last night my laptop died while in Ubuntu due to lack of battery power, when trying to boot back into Ubuntu this morning after plugging it in, the screen has the usual purple colour indicating that it is booting, then I'm met with a black screen and it won't boot.

I've left it for over two minutes on the black screen to see if anything happens. I can still boot into OSX fine.

Is there a way to pass 'noresume' into a boot sequence in rEFInd by pressing f2 f2 and entering a boot command? I'm not advanced enough to know what to enter on that menu.

If anyone has any advice it would be appreciated as I don't really want to nuke everything and reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a couple of times already. In the easy cases it was sufficient to access the grub boot-loader by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then selecting the ubuntu image.

This time I had to fiddle around a little more. My steps to fix it were:

1. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> on start-up to open boot-loader
2. Selecting the recovery image to boot (that one started luckily)
3. Logging in as `root` in the terminal
4. Running `fsck /dev/sda1` (while `sda1` is my boot mount)
5. Let `fsck` fix the issue (it find one for me)
6. Rebooting -> Done :)

I know it is a little bit late, but maybe that helps anybody else